# Domain name in a WordPress Network

Tags: multisite, apache, dns

I have a domain-based network. Blogs are like:

```
blog1.domain.com
blog2.domain.com
```

One of these blogs needs to be migrated to a domain *blog1.com*, but without leave the network. I know I have to poing *blog1.com* DNS to *blog1.domain.com* with a CNAME register (do it), but I don't know what to do now (in other case, not a wordpress network, I'll simply add a *ServerAlias* to Apache directive, but now I don't have any Apache directive for *blog1.domain.com*, just for *domain.com*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to accomplish this. See the installation tab on that page, it has excellent instructions!

Cheers~